# Why register access bandwidth is higher then residing inside CPU cache?

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-hardware

Access to registers claimed to be faster then cache. Why is it? Is it because cache has less wires or spatially further from functional units?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Where did you see that claimed?  Can you provide a citation and an excerpt?  What was the context?  What kind of cache were they talking about?  L1?  L2?  The more details you can give us, the more likely that we can help.

Comment: Just noticed my question is a bit misleading. In title I'm asking specifically about bandwidth. Why registers have higher bandwidth? It is claimed basically in any material about caches, for example the latest I saw it in video of Comp. Arch. course on Coursera

Comment: 1/ Are you sure that you are interested in bandwidth and not in latency? 2/ If you are interested in an hardware answer, electronics.se may be a better site for your question.

Comment: Accessing data from the register is faster than cache. Because all data is processed and handle within the register and there is no data fetching involved, however if the data is not stored within the register then that data needs to be fetched from the Cache or RAM then to the register. The Fetching process does take time or latency time before it gets to the register for processing, this also relates to cache hit or miss. A hit takes a constant time.

Answer (score 2):

There are slower and faster technologies for memory. And there are technologies for creating bigger or smaller amounts of memory. Obviously a technology that creates slower and smaller memory is useless. So of the useful technologies, the fastest one will always provide the smallest amount of memory, and the ones providing the biggest amount of memory will be the smallest.

Register memory is smaller than cache, therefore it's faster. It has nothing to do with technology, it is a basic economic principle. If the technology used for cache was faster, it would be used for registers.

Comment: I agree and understand economic principle but I'm interested in hardware explanation. Why it is works like this on hardware level?